# WPF Combobox lostfocus event become an Infinite lopp

Tags: wpf, combobox

please have look on my code,
this become an infinite loop while calling lostfocus event of combo box
i need some data from database and user can select data only  form list with typing options.

**mainwindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="112,10,0,0"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmb"  GotFocus="cmbgotfocus" LostKeyboardFocus="cmblost"  KeyDown="cmbkeydown" IsEditable="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="238" Margin="112,50,0,0"  />
</Grid>
```

**Class**

```
    private void cmbkeydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            cmb.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
    }

    private void cmblost(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmb.SelectedIndex < 0 && cmb.Text!="" )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid data from list only", "Warning");
            cmb.Focus();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Have vou tried to see what happens with a debugging tool?

Comment: calling cmb.Focus() in the lostfocus handler might not be a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you want user to type some text in the `ComboBox`, and if user's entry doesn't match any item, focus should remain on the `TextBox` present in the `ComboBox`.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Cmb1" IsEditable="True" 
          Control.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="Control_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" ...>
```

Handler code :

```
private void Control_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.OriginalSource is TextBox)) return;

        TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.OriginalSource;
        if (Cmb1.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            Cmb1.Text = "";
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Please tell if this solves your issue.